# How to display image from URL use pligg cms2.0

Tags: php, smarty, pligg

the  modifier
 `$string = preg_replace('/(http://|https://){1}.+?.(jpg|gif|bmp|bnp|png)$/is','<img src="$0" alt="" />',$string);

    return $string;`

How can I write in the link_summary.tpl

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say, just use upload module and choose the option upload image and link
This will display image from url